# ifnum: problem with multicolumn in tabular

Tags: tables, conditionals, multicol

The next code has an error

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\numtest}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\ifnum \numtest=1 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text} \else text E & text F \fi
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The idea is choose `\multicolumn` command in some cases. Furthermore, I would like to have several values for `\numtest` command, for example

```
\ifnum \numtest=1 OR \numtest=5 OR \numtest=17 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text} \else text E & text F \fi
```

I know I can do it with nested `ifnum`, but somebody knows another easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start a conditional in a cell and end it in another one, which would happen if the test is false.

You can use `\ifboolexpe` of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\numtest}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\ifboolexpe{
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{1}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{5}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{17}}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\numtest}{17}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\ifboolexpe{
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{1}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{5}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{17}}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\numtest}{42}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\ifboolexpe{
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{1}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{5}}
  or
  test {\ifnumequal{\numtest}{17}}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach uses `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gitanotest}{mmmm}
 {
  \int_case:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\numtest}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\gitanotest{\numtest}{
  {1}{}
  {5}{}
  {17}{}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\numtest}{17}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\gitanotest{\numtest}{
  {1}{}
  {5}{}
  {17}{}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\numtest}{42}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\gitanotest{\numtest}{
  {1}{}
  {5}{}
  {17}{}
}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}{text E & text F}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The arguments to `\gitanotest` are

1. The number to test
2. The matching cases; note the empty brace group after each one
3. The code to execute if a match is found
4. The code to execute if no match is found

The empty groups can actually contain code to execute for the particular match; not really useful here, but in other applications they may be.

The output is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Thanks, the option with \ifboolexpe of etoolbox works perfect and meets my needs

Answer (score 3):

You want to keep the if grouping within a single cell, you can implement or by nesting `\if` in various ways, the example tests 1 or 17.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\posmulcol[1]{%
\ifnum1=\numexpr0#1\relax
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numtest}{1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\posmulcol{\ifnum\numtest=1 1 \else\ifnum\numtest=17 1 \fi\fi}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{long text}}{text E &text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\numtest}{8}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\posmulcol{\ifnum\numtest=1 1 \else\ifnum\numtest=17 1 \fi\fi}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{long text}}{text E &text F}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\numtest}{17}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\posmulcol{\ifnum\numtest=1 1 \else\ifnum\numtest=17 1 \fi\fi}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{long text}}{text E &text F}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can store it in commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\numtest}{1}
  \def\mt{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}}
  \def\mtt{text E & text F}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text A & text B\\
text C & text D\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Long Text}\\
\ifnum \numtest=1  \mt\else  \mtt\fi
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```